# path to images in bookdown build through travis

Tags: r, r-markdown, travis-ci, bookdown

I have a [repository](https://github.com/nik0lai/learn2git) with a series of Rmd files that are build using `Bookdown`. Within those Rmd files, there is a call to images that are within a [folder](https://github.com/nik0lai/learn2git/tree/master/docs/non-plain/img) (also within the repository). If I open each Rmd file from the master branch the images are rendered correctly. However, I tried to build the book and push the built-book to a `gh-pages` branch (which also contains the images folder) using `Travis` and use Github pages but the images didn't render. The built book is [here](https://nik0lai.github.io/learn2git/).

To call the images within the Rmd files I use lines like this:

```
![**Fig. 0** Terminal en RStudio](./docs/non-plain/img/rstudio_terminal.png)
```

If I inspect the broken image in the built book the path contains locals folders of my computer, which I don't really understand given that all paths within the Rmd files are relative. I also tried to call the images using this (within an R code chunk) but it didn't work either:

`knitr::include_graphics("/docs/non-plain/img/config_git.png")`

I'm using a `.travis.yml`, taken from the Bookdown manual, that call a `_build.sh` and a `_deploy.sh` script.

**.travis.yml**

```
language: r
cache: packages
pandoc_version: 1.19.2.1

before_script:
  - chmod +x ./_build.sh
  - chmod +x ./_deploy.sh

script:
  - ./_build.sh
  - ./_deploy.sh
```

**_build.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

Rscript -e "bookdown::render_book('index.Rmd', 'bookdown::gitbook')"
```

**_deploy.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

[ -z "${GITHUB_PAT}" ] && exit 0
[ "${TRAVIS_BRANCH}" != "master" ] && exit 0

git config --global user.email "email.com"
git config --global user.name "username"

git clone -b gh-pages https://${GITHUB_PAT}@github.com/${TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG}.git book-output
cd book-output
cp -r ../_book/* ./
git add --all *
git commit -m"Update the book" || true
git push -q origin gh-pages
```

**I can't grasp what I'm doing wrong and why images are not being rendered properly. Any help is appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to use the url of the image on github as a path.

I have a similar problem using `bookdown::render_book()`, I think it is because images path is relative to the chapter .Rmd files, which are in a folder different from the index.Rmd

Comment: in this case:
`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nik0lai/learn2git/master/docs/non-plain/img/rstudio_terminal.png`